# Perform window.location.replace multiple times in for loop

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm not able to get my script to run `window.location.replace` multiple times. I have a flask application that create files given the unique ids found from streaming access logs on the server. Once the file is on the server, I have a flask route that if the user is redirected to `https://somewebsite.com/getFile/<id>`, it will than push the file that was created on the server to the client.

Here's my script below:

```
<script>

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

        var response = '';

        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            response = xhr.responseText;
            response = response.substring(0, response.length-1);
            response = response.split('\n');

            for(x in response){
                url_path = response[x];
                window.location.replace(url_path);
            };
        };
    };

    xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream')   }}', true);
    xhr.send();


</script>
```

I did a few `console.log()` calls to see if the for loop is running correctly and it is. Even the `url_path` given to `window.location.replace` is correct. One thing to note is that when being redirecting to `https://somewebsite.com/getFile/<id>`, the browser doesn't technically change to that url path, because flask isn't rendering a template, but instead returning a download file, so the browser stays at the current url path after the file is downloaded.

I'm not sure why I am not able to get the script to run `window.location.replace` more than once. It seems like if there's 2 url_path in the response object, only the last one is being downloaded. Same goes with 3 or 4 paths. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You could try using `window.location.assign` instead of `window.location.replace`

Comment: @LeoFarmer Thanks for the reply, I tried using `window.location.assign`, but it's still only downloading one file. I checked the server log and I only see one GET request, while the other one isn't . being performed. I added a `console.log` after the request and it prints both time.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution I just figured out was instead of redirecting the same browser to multiple urls, why not just open them up in different tabs. I did this by using `window.open`, which to my surprise did work.

However, my browser pop up blocker did block them out at first, but after changing the settings and allowing pop ups for the page, I was successfully able to have multiple files downloaded to the client. Also, since there's no template rendering on the server side, the tabs themselves don't actually pop up, so the browser won't be flooded with tabs.

I'm still interested in knowing why `window.location.replace` didn't work if anyone knows why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because what `window.location.replace` does is to literally replace the source document (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)) with the one provided by the new URL. 
What this means is that any code you put after `window.location.replace` won't be executed.

That is why window.open works perfectly for your situation, because it will open a new document apart from the one it is called. But be careful because not all parameters work for all browsers (check [this](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) for compatibility specifications).